# How to create layout look like following image in android and what is alpha in android layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

1. how to create layout look like [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51O5J.jpg) and this is my current layout [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sa2r.jpg)
2. what is alpha in android layout
3. it is possible to make card view transparent.
4. it is possible to make textview background transparent.

here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_dash_baord_lay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dash_board_car.d_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dash_board_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/defgall"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/dash_board_text"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_blue"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the image 1 contains the alpha and transparent background, i don't know to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dash_board_car.d_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dash_board_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/nilesh"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dash_board_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_marker"
            android:background="#82000000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]